# tabs navigation using html5 or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is my code:

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- Start Tabs !-->
    <div class="tab-container">    
        <div id="c1">
            <a href="#c1" title="Projects">Companies</a> <!-- This is your actual tab and the content is below it !-->
            <div class="tab-content">  <!-- tab-container > div > div in the CSS !-->
                <header id="companies">
                    <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;Companies(5)</h3>    
                </header>  
                <button id="create" onclick="addRow()">Create</button>

                <button id="edit">Edit</button> 
                <div id="table">
                    <table id="col">
                        <tr ><th>Company1</th></tr>
                        <tr><th>Comapny2</th></tr>
                        <tr><th>Company3</th></tr>
                        <tr><th>Company4</th></tr>
                        <tr><th>Company5</th></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have given css3 styling to these tabs . Now I want to make these rows also as tabs mena vertical tabs so that when I click it, It should display some data. Can anyone help me please and I want to so it using html5, css3 or jquery only.

Below is my existing css.

```
 <style>
    p, .tab-content li, h1, h2, h3{ /* This insures that there's enough space between your paragraphs, headings, etc */
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    a{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:black;
    }

    .tab-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        z-index:0;
        color:black;
        font-size:20px;
         border-style:solid;
        border-color:#FFFFFF;

    }
    #container{ /* Use this to position the entire tab module */

        width:1000px;
         margin-top:20px;




    }

     .tab-container > div {
        display:inline;
    } 

    .tab-container > div > a {
        position:relative;
     /* Keeps the tabs in line with each other */
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
         display: inline-block; 
        padding: 4px 14px;
        font-size:15px;
        font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight:normal;
        margin-top:2px;
         background: #E5E4E2;  /* old browsers */ 
        width:70px;
        height:40px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#D1D0CE;
    }

    .tab-container > div > a:hover {
        /* background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #948a81; */
        background: #B6B6B4;
    }

    .tab-container > div > div{ /* This is the container which holds the tab content */

         background-color:#FFFFFF;
         z-index:0;
        top: 75px;
       padding:0px 5px 15px 20px;
        min-height:500px;
        position:absolute; /* Fixes IE 7 & 8 */
        outline-offset: -8px;

    }

    .tab-container > div:target > div {
        position: absolute;
         z-index: 3 !important;  /* Brings the content to the front depending on the tab that was clicked */
    }




    /******  This imports other stylesheets so you don't have to call them in an html file *****/
    @import url('../../reset.css');
     div.tab-content{     
          width:1000px;
        margin-top:20px;
        display:table;
    }

    button{


        padding: 4px 14px;

         background: #E5E4E2;  /* old browsers */ 
        width: 80px;
        height: 30px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#D1D0CE;
        margin-top:20px;
    }





     button:hover{
    background: #B6B6B4;

    }
    #table tr>th{

      float:left;
      background-color:#EFECE5;
      layout-grid:vertical-ideographic;
      padding:50;
      margin-left:0px;
       height:50px;
       margin-top:20px;
       width:300px;
       border-color:#E5E4E2;
       text-align:left;
       border-width:2px;
       border-style: solid;
    }

    #table tr>th:hover{

     background: #B6B6B4;

     }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show some data from these tabs use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#tabid").click(function() {
  $("#tabdata").show();
 )}
)}
```

This way you can show the data from each tab. On the click.
**Note** The click isn't the only function, you can set the hover object too. To change the data if there is a hover over the tab.
You can hide one div, and show the other! Thats how it can be done by jQuery. Else if you want to load the data after the page loads. Use jQuery AJax as:

```
$.ajax({
 // here should be the ajax properties, such as page name data to load and   
 on success, on fail, on error.
})
```

Comment: @jerone can u give some demo